# Set::setps: in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm defining a function in *Mathematica* where if the i-th value in a list in 1, and the i+1-th value is 0, the function switches those two values.

I've defined it as:

```
f[i_, x_] := (If[x[[i]] == 1 && x[[i + 1]] == 0, x[[i]] = 1; x[[i + 1]] = 0]);
```

However when I test it with `i = 2` and `x = {1,1,0,0}` I get the following error:

> Set::setps: {1,1,0,0} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

I don't quite know what I'm doing wrong, as I thought I was calling everything correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have found a solution but let's break this down anyway.

First you have a simple transcription error where your `Set`s apply the original values rather than swapping them.  With this change the basic code works:

```
i = 2;
x = {1, 1, 0, 0};

If[
 x[[i]] == 1 && x[[i + 1]] == 0,
 x[[i]] = 0; x[[i + 1]] = 1;
]

x
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 1, 0}
> ```

So we have successfully changed `x`.  To make this into a function we must pass the *name* of `x` to this code rather than the *value* of `x`.  This is the source of your error:

```
{1, 1, 0, 0}[[2]] = 0;
```

> Set::setps: {1,1,0,0} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

What you need is a Hold attribute on your function:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]

f[i_, x_] := If[x[[i]] == 1 && x[[i + 1]] == 0, x[[i]] = 0; x[[i + 1]] = 1;]

i = 2 ;
x = {1, 1, 0, 0};

f[2, x]

x
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 1, 0}
> ```

Perhaps you did not intend to change the value of `x` itself but this technique will surely come in handy in other applications.  To modify the function above to manipulate a *copy* of the data we may use `Module`, and we don't need the Hold attribute:

```
f2[i_, xImmutable_] :=
  Module[{x = xImmutable},
    If[x[[i]] == 1 && x[[i + 1]] == 0, x[[i]] = 0; x[[i + 1]] = 1];
    x
  ]

i = 2 ;
x = {1, 1, 0, 0};

f2[2, x]
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 1, 0}
> ```

Notice that `x` within `Module` is a local variable and not your global list `x`, which remains unchanged.

For fun let's implement this in a different way.

```
f3[i_, x_] := 
 If[
   x[[i + {0, 1}]] == {1, 0},
   ReplacePart[x, {i -> 0, i + 1 -> 1}],
   x
 ]

f3[2, x]
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 1, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; I needed to not change the value of x itself.  Ooops!